# Django application: the directory_name to which an image has to be uploaded, should be auto populated

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm, image-upload

I want to upload images to the django server using my application and the folder/directory_name to which the image has to be uploaded, should be auto populated using the foreignkey relationship that my models are sharing

My models classes are as follows,

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_desc = models.CharField(max_length=5000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='events/{}'.format("something"))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image_name
```

the `something` in the models.ImageField function has to be replaced by the `event_name` dynamically and the value for `event_name` should be populated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callable to the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to): which contains a reference to the model object, so you can redefine this to:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    def upload_image_to(instance, filename):
        return f'events/{instance.event_id.event_name}/{filename}'
    
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_to)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image_name
```

You can change the filename as well, you can rewrite the `upload_image_to` function to:

```
def upload_image_to(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
    return f'events/{instance.event_id.event_name}/{instance.image_name}.{ext}'
```

Here we thus split right-to-left, and only retain the last part as extension.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `scene`, instead of <s>`scene_id`</s>.

Comment: thank you very much! it worked, though required a little more modifications for using the image name as the name of the image after the upload.

```python
def upload_image_to(instance, filename):
        return f'events/{instance.event_id.event_name}/{filename.replace(filename.split(".")[0], instance.image_name)}'
```

Comment: @GauthamKolluru: yes, I think I saw that exactly at the moment that you commented :)

Comment: @GauthamKolluru: you can perhaps make use of `rsplit` to work with filenames that contain dots like `foo.bar.jpg`.